# Moderncv classic cover letter error when using footnotes

Tags: errors, packages, footnotes, moderncv

I am writing a cover letter using the classic cover letter model, derived from moderncv, I found on the internet for LaTeX. I would like to add a footnote, so I import the package `footnote` and the use `\footnote{some text}` where I want to. This leads to two errors, which become just one if I remove the line `\usepackage{footnote}`.

Below, I report a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        
\moderncvstyle{classic}                            
\moderncvcolor{green}                              
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{footnote}

\name{XXX}{YYY}
\address{qwert}{Somewhere}{World}
\phone[mobile]{+1234568789}
\email{xxx.yyy@gmail.com}
\begin{document}

\recipient{Somebody}{Some street} 
\date{somewhere, \today}
\opening{Dear ,}
\closing{Yours, sincerely,}
\makelettertitle

\justify

Some text \footnote{Some other text}
\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

These errors do not seem  to impact the cover letter, however I would like to know Why I get these errors when I insert the footnote, and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: Your reputation points are now high enough you are allowed to vote up helpful answers. Please consider to do this with the answer below. It is the way to say "Thank You" here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with class `moderncv` is that is does **not** support footnotes.  That is the reason for the error message you get with your code.

But you can use class `scrlttr2` (KOMA-Script) or `letter` (did not test this) to create your letter with footnotes.

How to use `scrlttr2` with the style of `moderncv` please see my [answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132123/16550). With `scrlttr2` you can use footnotes ...